# Been trying to build new data frame from existing data frame and series

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I'm trying to write a loop that does the following:

```
df_f.ix[0] = df_n.loc[0]
df_f.ix[1] = h[0]
df_f.ix[2] = df_n.loc[1]
df_f.ix[3] = h[1]
df_f.ix[4] = df_n.loc[2]    
df_f.ix[5] = h[2]
...
df_f.ix[94778] = df_n.loc[47389]
df_f.ix[94779] = h[47389]
```

Basically, row 1 (and all the rows incremented by 2) of data frame df_f is equal to row 1 of data frame df_n (and its rows incremented by 1) and row 2 (and the rows incremented by 2) of df_f is equal to row 1 (and its rows incremented by 1) of series h. And so on...Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need loops... You can just create a new list of data from your existing data frame/series and then make that int a new DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

#example data
df_n = pd.DataFrame([1,2, 3, 4,5])
h = pd.Series([99, 98, 97, 96, 95])

new_data = [None] * (len(df_n) * 2)
new_data[::2] = df_n.loc[:, 0].values
new_data[1::2] = h.values
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)

In [135]: new_df
Out[135]: 
    0
0   1
1  99
2   2
3  98
4   3
5  97
6   4
7  96
8   5
9  95
```

If you really want a loop that will do it you could create an empty data frame like so:

```
other_df = pd.DataFrame([None] * (len(df_n) * 2))
y = 0
for x in xrange(len(df_n)):
    other_df.loc[y] = df_n.loc[x]
    y+=1
    other_df.loc[y] = h[x]
    y+=1

In [136]: other_df
Out[136]: 
    0
0   1
1  99
2   2
3  98
4   3
5  97
6   4
7  96
8   5
9  95
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do in Numpy. You can retrieve the data from a Pandas Dataframe using `df.values`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df_a, df_b = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4]), pd.DataFrame([5, 6, 7, 8])
>>> df_a
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
>>> df_b
   0
0  5
1  6
2  7
3  8
>>> np_a, np_b = df_a.values, df_b.values
>>> np_a
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
>>> np_b
array([[5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8]])
>>> np_c = np.hstack((np_a, np_b))
>>> np_c
array([[1, 5],
       [2, 6],
       [3, 7],
       [4, 8]])
>>> np_c = np_c.flatten()
>>> np_c
array([1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8])
>>> df_c = pd.DataFrame(np_c)
>>> df_c
   0
0  1
1  5
2  2
3  6
4  3
5  7
6  4
7  8
```

All of this in one line, given df_a and df_b:

```
>>> df_c = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((df_a.values, df_b.values)).flatten())
>>> df_c
   0
0  1
1  5
2  2
3  6
4  3
5  7
6  4
7  8
```

Edit:
If you have more than one column, which is the general case,

```
>>> df_a = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> df_b = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]])
>>> df_a
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
>>> df_b
   0  1
0  5  6
1  7  8
>>> np_a = df_a.values
>>> np_a = np_a.reshape(np_a.shape[0], 1, np_a.shape[1])
>>> np_a
array([[[1, 2]],

       [[3, 4]]])
>>> np_b = df_b.values
>>> np_b = np_b.reshape(np_b.shape[0], 1, np_b.shape[1])
>>> np_b
array([[[5, 6]],

       [[7, 8]]])
>>> np_c = np.concatenate((np_a, np_b), axis=1)
>>> np_c
array([[[1, 2],
        [5, 6]],

       [[3, 4],
        [7, 8]]])
>>> np_c = np_c.reshape(np_c.shape[0] * np_c.shape[2], np_c.shape[1])
>>> np_c
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6],
       [3, 4],
       [7, 8]])
>>> df_c = pd.DataFrame(np_c)
```